# POLYMORPHISM - Design a database connection and command

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented, polymorphism

**> Exercise 1: Design a database connection**

> To access a database, we need to open a connection to it first and close it once our job is done.
>   Connecting to a database depends on the type of the target database and the database
>   management system (DBMS). For example, connecting to a SQL Server database is different
>   from connecting to an Oracle database. But both these connections have a few things in
>   common:
>
> • They have a connection string\
>   • They can be opened\
>   • They can be closed\
>   • They may have a timeout attribute (so if the connection could not be opened within the
>   timeout, an exception will be thrown).\
>
> Your job is to represent these commonalities in a base class called DbConnection. This class
>   should have two properties:
>
> ConnectionString : string\
>   Timeout : TimeSpan
>
> A DbConnection will not be in a valid state if it doesn’t have a connection string. So you need to
>   pass a connection string in the constructor of this class. Also, take into account the scenarios
>   where null or an empty string is sent as the connection string. Make sure to throw an exception
>   to guarantee that your class will always be in a valid state.
>
> Our DbConnection should also have two methods for opening and closing a connection. We
>   don’t know how to open or close a connection in a DbConnection and this should be left to the
>   classes that derive from DbConnection. These classes (eg SqlConnection or OracleConnection)
>   will provide the actual implementation. So you need to declare these methods as abstract.
>
> Derive two classes SqlConnection and OracleConnection from DbConnection and provide a
>   simple implementation of opening and closing connections using Console.WriteLine(). In the
>   real-world, SQL Server provides an API for opening or closing a connection to a database. But
>   for this exercise, we don’t need to worry about it.

**>Exercise 2: Design a database command**

> Now that we have the concept of a DbConnection, let’s work out how to represent a DbCommand.
>
> Design a class called DbCommand for executing an instruction against the database. A
>   DbCommand cannot be in a valid state without having a connection. So in the constructor of
>   this class, pass a DbConnection. Don’t forget to cater for the null.
>
> Each DbCommand should also have the instruction to be sent to the database. In case of SQL
>   Server, this instruction is expressed in T-SQL language. Use a string to represent this instruction.
>   Again, a command cannot be in a valid state without this instruction. So make sure to receive it
>   in the constructor and cater for the null reference or an empty string.
>
> Each command should be executable. So we need to create a method called Execute(). In this
>   method, we need a simple implementation as follows:
>
> Open the connection.
>   Run the instruction.
>   Close the connection.
>
> Note that here, inside the DbCommand, we have a reference to DbConnection. Depending on
>   the type of DbConnection sent at runtime, opening and closing a connection will be different.
>   For example, if we initialize this DbCommand with a SqlConnection, we will open and close a
>   connection to a Sql Server database. This is polymorphism. Interestingly, DbCommand doesn’t
>   care about how a connection is opened or closed. It’s not the responsibility of the DbCommand.
>   All it cares about is to send an instruction to a database.
>
> For running the instruction, simply output it to the Console. In the real-world, SQL Server (or any
>   other DBMS) provides an API for running an instruction against the database. We don’t need to
>   worry about it for this exercise.
>
> In the main method, initialize a DbCommand with some string as the instruction and a
>   SqlConnection. Execute the command and see the result on the console.
>
> Then, swap the SqlConnection with an OracleConnection and see polymorphism in action

I know that is a lot to read for reference.  Not sure why this was worded the way it was.  At this point I'm sure I will learn more here than whatever the intentions of this was from the author.  All I gather is that this was an attempt to teach abstract and virtual methods.  To my knowledge everything works here and I would be grateful to just get a better understanding of this and perhaps shown a better approach to this than whatever the author had in mind.

**DbCommand.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DesignDatabaseConnection
{
    public class DbCommand
    {
        private readonly DbConnection _dbconnection;
        public DbConnection Dbconnection => _dbconnection;

        private readonly string _instruction;

        internal DbCommand(string instruction, DbConnection dbConnection)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_instruction))
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            _instruction = instruction;
            _dbconnection = dbConnection;
        }


        public void Execute()
        {
            Dbconnection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Running the instruction");
            Dbconnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**DbConnection.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DesignDatabaseConnection
{
    public abstract class DbConnection
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private readonly TimeSpan _timeout;

        public string ConnectionString => _connectionString;
        public TimeSpan Timeout => _timeout;

        public DbConnection(string connectionString, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            _connectionString = connectionString;
            _timeout = timeout;
        }

        public abstract void Open();
        public abstract void Close();
    }
}
```

**OracleConnection.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DesignDatabaseConnection
{
    public class OracleConnection : DbConnection
    {
        public OracleConnection(string connectionString, TimeSpan timeout) : base(connectionString, timeout)
        {
        }

        public override void Open() => Console.WriteLine("Database is open.");
        public override void Close() => Console.WriteLine("Database is closed.");

    }
}
```

**SqlConnection.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DesignDatabaseConnection
{
    public class SqlConnection : DbConnection
    {
        public SqlConnection(string connectionString, TimeSpan timeout) : base(connectionString, timeout)
        {
        }

        public override void Open() => Console.WriteLine("Database is open.");
        public override void Close() => Console.WriteLine("Database is closed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you see adapter abd bridge pattern and also how the   .Net framework implemented it

Comment: I'll give it a read.  Thank you.

Comment: @Gilad was this the purpose of pointing that out for me to read [The main difference between an adaptor and a bridge pattern, is that a bridge pattern serves to decouple an abstraction class from its implementation, and an adaptor pattern converts the interface between classes with less inheritance.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10053/Refactoring-To-Patterns-Bridge-and-Adapter-Pattern)

Comment: @Miiliorn the purpose is to point out how this is already done in the .Net framework and how it should be done in order of preserving S.O.L.I.D principles.

Comment: I assume there is nothing left to add or improve upon?